# Value and references when providing a closure to Iterator::find

Tags: rust

I have still quite a long way to go in learning Rust, but I find the way values and references are used to be inconsistent. This may be born from my own ignorance of the language.

For example, this works:

```
let x = (1..100).find(|a| a % 2 == 0);
```

But `let x = (1..100).find(|a| a > 50);` does not. I am not sure - why though?

Using `let x = (1..100).find(|&a| a > 50);` fixes the error, but then I thought using `&a` is like asking for reference of element from the range and hence following should work, but it does not:

```
let x = (1..100).find(|&a| *a > 50);
```

Again no idea why!

Comment: I tried to improve your title from the overly generic *"value and references"*. Please feel free to update it to better suit your real question - note that there are no question marks anywhere in your post, so you haven't actually asked anything yet!

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question to make it more pointed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but then I thought using &a is like asking for reference of element from the range

*This* is the wrong part of your reasoning. Using `&` in pattern does exactly the opposite - it implicitly dereferences the matched value:

```
let &a = &10;
// a is 10, not &10 or &&10
```

As you probably already know, `find()` accepts a closure which satisfies `FnMut(&T) -> bool`, that is, this closure accepts a reference to each element of the iterator, so if you write `(1..100).find(|a| ...)`, `a` will be of type `&i32`.

`let x = (1..100).find(|a| a % 2 == 0)` works because arithmetic operators are overloaded to work on references, so you can apply `%` to a reference and it still would be able to compile.

Comparison operators are not overloaded to handle references, and so you need to get an `i32` from `&i32`. This could be done in two ways, first, like you already did:

```
let x = (1..100).find(|&a| a > 50)
```

Here we use `&` patterns to implicitly dereference the function argument. It is equivalent to this one:

```
let x = (1..100).find(|a| { let a = *a; a > 50 })
```

Another way would be to dereference the argument explicitly:

```
let x = (1..100).find(|a| *a > 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-trivial patterns usually *destructure* something, i.e., break something into its components. This usually mirrors some *construction* syntax, so it looks very similar but is actually the inverse. This dualism applies to records, to tuples, to boxes (once those are properly implemented), and also to references:

- The *expression* `&x` creates a reference to whatever `x` evaluates to. Here, the `&` turns a value of type `T` into one of type `&T`.
- The *pattern* `&a`, on the other hand,  eliminates the reference, so `a` is bound to what is *behind* the reference (note that `a` could also be another, more complicated pattern). Here, the `&` goes from a `&T` value to a `T` value.

The closures in your examples are all of of type `&i32 -> bool`<sup>1</sup>. So they accept a reference to an integer, and you can either work with that reference (which you do in the first example, which works because arithmetic operators are overloaded for references too) or you can use the pattern `&a`. In the latter case, `a` is a `i32` (compare the general explanation above, substitute `i32` for `T`), so of course you can't dereference it further.

<sup>1</sup> This is not actually a real type, but it's close enough for our purposes.

Comment: @Shepmaster Now that you mention it, I've only ever seen "destructure". I thought I've seen "deconstructing" too (which makes the dualism clearer) but I'm not so sure anymore. I'll edit it.

Comment: Perfect. I did guess that `%`  implicitly works  with references while comparison does not. I guess there should be a section in rust docs about this stuff. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I thought using &a is like asking for reference of element from the range

Sometimes `&` is used as an operator, and sometimes it is used as a pattern match. For the closure parameter (`|&a|`), it is being used as a pattern match. This means that the variable `a` will be automatically dereferenced when it is used. It is also equivalent to do

```
let x = (1..100).find(|a| *a > 50);
```